# Multi-lingual site in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I started using the framework for php: Laravel 5.

I'm trying to implement in my website a possibility to translate to different languages. I just recently started learning how to code using this website and it's kind of complicated because there's not enought information in the internet.

Does anybody can help me?
I know that I have to specify in the **routes.php** file the instruction to make this, but I honestly don't know how to do it.

I will appreciate any suggestions about the topic.

Greetings

Comment: This question is too broad in its current format. As for there not being enough information on the Internet for Laravel: that statement is laughable. Laravel’s perhaps the most popular PHP framework today with tons of resources, which is impressive when you think it’s one of the youngest too.

Comment: I appreciate your comments and I apologize for the writing misunderstanding. When I said I haven't found any information related to this framework, I mean it's difficult for someone who's starting using it try to understand it. If you could recommend me a guide I could follow to improve the use of this frameworkd, I will apreciate it @MartinBean

Comment: Funny you should ask that, I wrote a book on it: http://bit.ly/l5amazon ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some pretty good documentation on this found here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/localization

The concept is fairly simple.  You create a subdirectory for each language you wish to support and within that subdirectory, you add files which contain the language you wish to the support.  You then use the `Lang` class which will look in the appropriate files to grab the correct text to display.

Comment: Sir you look like a experienced user but still referencing to documents of Laravel 4.2 when actually the tags this user has used for the question says Laravel laravel-5 laravel-routing and php